# postgresql restore after pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql

Here are the sequence of steps

1. Created a new table, inserted a record -

```
create table t (c1 int);
insert into t values(1);
```

2. Took pg_basebackup
3. Inserted another record

```
insert into t values(2);
```

4. Copied the pg_basebackup into a restore directory, removed pg_wal directory and copied it from the database so that it includes 2nd record.
5. Started up the restore database, but I only see record 1 in the restored database.

Is my approach of copying the latest wals correct to be able to do restore? If yes then why is the record not restored? If not, then what should be my approach to be able to restore the database with updates after pg_basebackup (without taking another backup)?

Comment: You didn't remove `backup_label`, did you? What do you see in the PostgreSQL log? It is definitely wrong to remove `pg_wal`, that is probably your problem.

Comment: What options were given to pg_basebackup?  What version?

Comment: @jjanes -bash-4.2$ pg_basebackup --version
pg_basebackup (PostgreSQL) 13.2.5